# Register tableView finished loading with willDisplayCell - doesn't work with 0 results

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to alert the user that there are 0 results if my tableView has nothing to display. I am doing this in my willDisplayCell method, but it does not register if there are 0 results. Does anyone know how to go about revising this? Thank you!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] 
lastObject]).row) {

    if ([self.listItems count] == 0) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results" message:@"No 
        results found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show alert in your `viewWillAppear` method your `willDisplayCell` method not called since your number of rows are 0 and if you closely look at your `willDisplayCell` method you will find a parameter `forRowAtIndexPath`, that's why it's not getting called as number of rows are zero.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {

    if ([self.listItems count] == 0)
    {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Results" message:@"No 
       results found" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
       [tableView reloadData];
    }
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the viewWillAppear method gets called before my query is run - thus I don't know how many results there are

Comment: then use above code snippets after your query returns result and you are reloading your table

Comment: Hi Aman, Im not sure what you mean by "use above code snippets." I have put that code in my viewWillAppear method and it still loads too quickly

Comment: by this "use above code snippets." i meant to copy the lines written in viewWillAppear method, and paste them after your query returns results